# Kinematics and dynamics analysis of manipulator in zero gravity

Tags: manipulator

Is there any change in the analysis of kinematic and dynamic analysis of the manipulator which is working in zero gravity or microgravity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinematics is based on geometry and joint constraints, so no change there at all.

Dynamic motion results from the sum of forces, so the only change to a dynamic analysis is that you don't include gravity, but all other forces would remain.

Comment: I guess important to note on the zero-gravity scenario is that there is no "grounding" connection for the actuator. You might be able to get by with an assumption that the actuator is much less massive than the object to which it's attached (small robot arm on a space station, for example), but you should be aware that the base *will* move, and that the motion of the base could be significant (large arm on a small satellite, for example).

Comment: Thank you Chuck for answer,